# Chrome: bookmark an application?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

In Chrome I have several applications in `chrome://apps`.

How can I bookmark these apps, or otherwise make a shortcut to them?

Answer (score 0):

This can be conveniently done using the powerful Apps Launcher extension:

1. Install the [Apps Launcher extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apps-launcher/ijmgkhchjindcjamnckoiahagecjnkdc?hl=en)
2. Show launcher using keyboard shortcut Ctrl + .
3. Navigate through apps using arrow keys